# Git: Commit Only Specified Files (Renamed, Deleted, Modified, New File, etc)

Tags: regex, git, rename, git-commit

I've got an older project where I modified many files (more than a hundred). Removed several, renamed a whole bunch, deleted many, etc. There are probably 10 or more commits worth in this batch of changes. How do I write a commit command to select, for example, only those renamed files:

`git commit "all renamed files" -m "Renamed files."`

I'd like to try and avoid doing something like this:

`git commit file1 file2 file3 -m "Renamed files."`

...because there are too many. I could also commit a folders worth (`git commit folder1 . . .`) but, unfortunately, there are some files in the folders that aren't to be committed.

I've accepted the answer provided but had to modify the command a bit:

```
git status --porcelain | grep -E '^(.R|R.)' | \
cut -b4- | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git commit -m "Bulk renamed files."
```

The reason for this is because running `git status --porcelain | grep -E '^(.R|R.)' | cut -b4-`, for example, outputs (here's one line to demonstrate): `source/__init__.py -> site/__init__.py`. When I use `xargs` to run the `commit` command, it's not accepted, presumably because of the `-> . . .` part. So I use `awk` here to select the first chunk only and this works nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `git status --porcelain` to select only the files of a certain type.  For example, to select only renamed files, use something like the following:

```
$ git status --porcelain | grep -E '^(.R|R.)' | cut -b4- | \
  xargs git commit -m 'Renamed files'
```

The letters that are output and their meanings can be seen by running `git status --help`.

Comment: only need to use ``` cut -d">" -f2 ```